# Cross Math Program

Tags: c++, permutation

Every so often we are assigned Cross Math Puzzles to do. I decided to write a C++ program that would solve the cross math problem. I built the following program, but for some reason whenever I run it with this combination of numbers and operators, the program just outputs done, and does not provide the actual numbers. My question, to be concise, is why exactly is this the case, and how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){

     int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

     do{
          //Horizontal tests
          if ((numbers[0] + numbers[1]) - numbers[2] != 7)
               continue;
          if ((numbers[3] * numbers[4]) * numbers[5] != 6)
               continue;
          if ((numbers[6] * numbers[7]) / numbers[8] != 4)
               continue;
          //Vertical tests
          if ((numbers[0] * numbers[3]) - numbers[6] != 1)
               continue;
          if ((numbers[1] + numbers[4]) - numbers[7] != 4)
               continue;
          if ((numbers[2] / numbers[5]) - numbers[8] != 2)
               continue;
          std::cout << "got a number..." << std::endl;
          for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
               std::cout << numbers[i] << " ";
               if (i == 2 || i == 5)
                    std::cout << std::endl;
          }
          std::cout << std::endl;
          break;
     } while (std::next_permutation(numbers, numbers + 9));
     std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

> ```
> The current code represents this cross math puzzle:
>
> [0] + [1] - [2] = 7
>  *     +     /
> [3] * [4] * [5] = 6
>  -     -     -
> [6] + [7] / [8] = 4
>  =     =     =
>  1     4     2
>
>  (where [x] is the index in the array)
> ```

Comment: are you sure there is a solution?

Comment: There should be, yes

Comment: Then start with that solution as your initial array configuration and see where the program breaks down with a debugger. Your program runs over all permutations, my guess is that there's no solution. Also consider putting the tests into a separate `bool` function that returns `true` if the tests pass.

Comment: [Learning how to use a debugger will be one of the most important skillsets you could ever acquire as a developer](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/28767/).

Comment: As long as each cell must have different number, there is no solution, sorry. `[3] * [4] * [5] = 6` means that the middle row has `1, 2, 3` (in any order). Since they are taken, you cannot satisfy the last row. If a number may appear in the multiple cells, do not use permutations.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ((numbers[6] * numbers[7]) / numbers[8] != 4)
               continue;
```

this line doesn't match your statement below

```
[0] + [1] - [2] = 7
 *     +     /
[3] * [4] * [5] = 6
 -     -     -
[6] + [7] / [8] = 4
 =     =     =
 1     4     2
```

(where `[x]` is the index in the array)